# <img> validation if its a img url

Tags: javascript, validation

How to validate if the `<img src ="<img URL>">` is valid. Everytime I ran my code and input a non url image it will always display error 
asd:1 GET `file:///F:/Practice_site/htdocs/copy_html_activities/html_activities/activity%205/asd 0 ()`

Please help me to put some validation and get rid of the error

**my js:**

```
function delete_row(no)
{

    document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}


function add_row()
{   
     var new_image=document.getElementById("new_image").value;
     var new_title=document.getElementById("new_title").value;
     var new_description=document.getElementById("new_description").value;
    if (new_image&&new_title&&new_description != "") {
         var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
         var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
         var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML=
         "<div id='row"+table_len+"'><div id='image_row"+table_len+"'><img src = "+new_image+"></div><div id='title_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_title+
         "</div><div id='age_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_description+"</div><div><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></div></div>";

         document.getElementById("new_image").value="";
         document.getElementById("new_title").value="";
         document.getElementById("new_description").value="";
     }
}

function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "/images/no_photo.jpg";
    return true;
}
```

I will be glad if anyone can help me solve this problem. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a promise that checks if the image is valid:

```
function isValidImg( url ) {
    return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {

        var image = new Image;

        image.onload = function ( ) { resolve( image ) };
        image.onerror = image.onabort = reject;

        image.src = url;
    } );
}
```

and in your code:

```
function add_row()
{   
    var new_image=document.getElementById("new_image").value;
    isValidImg(new_image)
    .then(function() {
        var new_title=document.getElementById("new_title").value;
        var new_description=document.getElementById("new_description").value;
        if (new_image&&new_title&&new_description != "") {
            var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
            var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML=
            "<div id='row"+table_len+"'><div id='image_row"+table_len+"'><img src = "+new_image+"></div><div id='title_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_title+
            "</div><div id='age_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_description+"</div><div><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></div></div>";

            document.getElementById("new_image").value="";
            document.getElementById("new_title").value="";
            document.getElementById("new_description").value="";
        }
    })
    .catch(function() {
        alert('Error! Not a valid image.')
        // do what you need to do here if the image is not valid
    })
}
```

Comment: Why not use the native `try{}catch{}then{}` mechanism, which is built exactly for handling errors?
Promise actually uses `try{}catch{}then{}` in its catch function.
This code in not asyncronus, it basically executes line by line without waiting, so why should he use Promises?

Comment: @hazy 
You should read my comment above.
Using `try{}catch{}then{}` is much more optimal, there is no need to use Promises here, Promises are for async operations, which this is not.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very vague, I'm guessing your using vanilla ES5.
an image source should be ether a static resource, or, It is possible to insert a link to a dynamically, server generated, image... but it needs server co-op to do that, and it sounds like your doing only client-side work here.

first things first:

HTMLImgElements do not have a value attribute, so the following:

```
var new_image=document.getElementById("new_image").value;
```

will not assign anything to the **new_image** veraiable, it will stay **undefined**, this is unless you assigned a **value** attribute & its value somewhere else in your code, but it does not show in this example.

The same goes for

```
var new_description=document.getElementById("new_description").value;
```

By looking at the code you added, I cannot see any element that has the ID of  "new_description", if thats the case this line will yield a type error: "cannot resolve value property of undefined". and even if you do have an element with that id, **HTMLTextNodes** also do not have a value property so the **new_description** veriable will stay **undefined**.

Basically this code is a mess.

another thing is, you probably very new to javascript since for handelling errors you should use the **try catch mechanism**:

```
try{}catch(e){}then{}
```

So you could try something like this:

```
function add_row()
{   
    try{


     var new_image=document.getElementById("new_image").value;
     var new_title=document.getElementById("new_title").value;
     var new_description=document.getElementById("new_description").value;
    if (new_image&&new_title&&new_description != "") {
         var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
         var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
         var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML=
         "<div id='row"+table_len+"'><div id='image_row"+table_len+"'><img src = 
         "+new_image+"></div><div id='title_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_title+
         "</div><div id='age_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_description+"</div><div><input 
         type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' 
         onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'> 
          </div></div>";
           document.getElementById("new_image").value="";
         document.getElementById("new_title").value="";
         document.getElementById("new_description").value="";
  }
  catch(e){

  // YOUR ERROR IS HERE IN THE ERROR OBJECT OF e

  }   



  }
```